# why does an empty get_the_excerpt change get_the_ID to default homepage?

Tags: plugins, excerpt

Using a post-carousel plugin, the following error is occurring after one line of code executes (the get_the_excerpt command only):

If the_excerpt for the current $post is **empty**, this is the result:

One line before the command, get_the_ID = 17457 (correct)

```
$pcp_post_content = get_the_excerpt();
```

One line after, get_the_ID = 9376 (incorrect -- this is the default homepage / root URL)

---

If the_excerpt is **NOT empty**, this is the result (correct behavior):

get_the_ID = 17457 (correct)

```
$pcp_post_content = get_the_excerpt();
```

get_the_ID = 17457 (correct)

After some googling, I tried a suggestion to insert a setup_postdata() command, which did not change the outcome.

Since this is running in a somewhat complex plugin, I'm not 100% sure if it is running inside or outside the Loop, but it does work correctly if the_excerpt has content.

Any suggestions or learned experience with this kind of behavior?

TIA

Comment: On what page did the issue happen - a single post (e.g. at `example.com/post-slug`), a category archive, or? And where on that page - is it in the sidebar, footer, or? Have you tried deactivating all plugins except the carousel plugin and if yes, did the same issue persist?

Comment: Thanks Sally. This issue appears on the homepage, as the first content item — a post carousel of the 5 most recent posts.

Face palm… no I haven’t yet deactivated all other plugins. I’ll do that now and report back here in this thread.

Comment: This issue turned out to be a conflict between two plugins. Resolved.